# Drop rows with NaNs based on combination of different columns subsets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to drop all rows with NaN values based on combinations of columns subsets. Let's demonstrate this on simple example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, np.nan, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4], [1, np.nan, np.nan, 4], [1, 2, np.nan, np.nan]],
    columns=["a1", "a2", "b1", "b2"],
)

print(df)
#    a1   a2   b1   b2
# 0  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0
# 1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
# 2  NaN  NaN  3.0  4.0
# 3  1.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
# 4  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
```

And I would like to drop rows where **all** features in either sets `{a1, a2}` or `{b1, b2}` are NaN. So the output would be (rows number 2 and 4 dropped):

```
   a1   a2   b1   b2
0  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
3  1.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

I would ideally need some combination of `df.dropna(how="all", subset=["a1", "a2"])` and `df.dropna(how="all", subset=["b1", "b2"])`. In this simple case it would not be such problem but what about having e.g. 10 different subsets? (And in my real scenario it's almost 50.)

Is there any smart solution using pandas or any filter how to combine these subsets and make the right condition for `dropna` method?

***Motivation**: Just to give you an idea why I need something like this it's because I have different sets of features (`a`, `b`, ...) that are combined in a single DataFrame and I need to handle those features separately. Some NaNs are ok, but if any row for any feature is full of NaNs, it means wrong measurement and I want to drop this row for any other feature as well (just imagine that the index is time of measurement and if a single set of features is incorrect I do not want to keep it even if other sets of features are fine).*

Comment: If you have a generator function that can generate the column subsets, then you could use that to specify your dropna subsets in a loop. Aside from that, I do not immediately know of a way to do this

Comment: @Nerxis Can the subset be any combination of columns for example `{'a1', 'b2'}` or `{'c1', 'd2'}`?

Comment: Yes, it might be. In my case it's usually something `{"temp_sensor_1", "temp_sensor_2", "temp_ambient", ...}` and other like `{"volt_p_phase_a", "volt_s_phase_a", "volt_main_lv_phase_a", ...}` and so on. But generally it might be any combination, it depends on group of sensors so even different kind of measurements can be in a single group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Approach

For each `subset` in the list of predefined `subsets` you can test the columns of that subset for the presence of any non `NaN` value along `axis=1` to create a boolean mask, then you can [`reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) all the boolean masks corresponding to each of the subset with [`np.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) to create a resulting boolean `mask` which then can be used to filter the rows in the dataframe.

```
subs = [{'a1', 'a2'}, {'b1', 'b2'}]
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df[s].notna().any(1) for s in subs])
```

#### Result

```
>>> df[mask]

    a1   a2   b1   b2
0  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
3  1.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: @jezrael: Thank you both for your solution, I will accept this answer because of two reasons - it's more general (works with any subset, for the latter with groupby I would need to use some mapping) and for large DataFrames it's much faster.

Answer (score 1):

First compare all values for not missing values, then group by first letter of columsnn ames with [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) for test if groups has no only NaNs and last filter by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for get all rows matching masks:

```
print (df.columns.str[0])
Index(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], dtype='object')


print (df.notna().groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).any())
       a      b
0   True   True
1   True   True
2  False   True
3   True   True
4   True  False

df = df[df.notna().groupby(df.columns.str[0], axis=1).any().all(axis=1)]
print (df)
    a1   a2   b1   b2
0  1.0  NaN  3.0  4.0
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
3  1.0  NaN  NaN  4.0
```

Comment: That's a nice solution with `notna` method and grouping. Could you generalize your solution a bit to work with a custom groups (e.g. `{"a", "b"}` and `{"c", "d"}` where you cannot use `str[0]`)?

Comment: @Nerxis - Groupby need same values, so only possible solution is again use `df.columns.str[0]` and then map `a` to `a` and `b` to `a` for groups `a,a,a,a` in sample data. Not sure if understand what need.